# Trying to hide a paragraph when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement dark mode on my site. So when a button is clicked to go into dark mode, it should apply the "dark" class to the main div and apply the "invisible" class to the paragraph, to hide it in dark mode. When the button is clicked again it should remove the dark class and remove the invisible class. But the opposite is happening, the paragraph is hidden in the light mode and unhidden in the dark mode. Send help.

```js
document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".main").classList.toggle("dark");
  document.querySelector(".main p").classList.toggle("invisible");
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Fredoka', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

p {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 30px 0px 20px;
}

.main {
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.dark {
  background-color: #1a1919;
  color: white;
}

.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <h1 class="heading">Hey there!</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p> Welcome to my cool little website that has a dark mode functionality. <br> If you're an uncultured **** who prefers light mode, then please leave. <br> But if you're not, then click the button below.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn">Dark Mode</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the HTML markup involved and your attempts to resolve the problem. That's so little code that it shouldn't be too hard to use your browser's debugger for this

Comment: @NicoHaase just added the markup..please tell me if you need anything else

Comment: I don't see any code that does what you describe for subsequent clicks. What have you tried? What's the question?

Comment: @isherwood all the code is there...like i said i'm using the toggle method to add and remove classes on subsequent clicks.

Comment: I put your code into a proper snippet demo (again), and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
    document.querySelector(".main").classList.toggle("dark");

if(document.querySelector(".main").classList.contains("dark"))
    document.querySelector(".main p").classList.remove("invisible");
else 
    document.querySelector(".main p").classList.add("invisible");
})
```

Comment: yeah that code works but I wanna know why I can't toggle both at the same time?